# Selective sticky sessions with JEE

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, wildfly, sticky

I have an application with REST API (JAX-RS) - these APIs are of course stateless. There is a **second part**, website administration based on JSF, which uses sessions (session scoped beans).

I would like to have multiple nodes with the application deployed, hidden behind a load balancer (any loadbanacer). Is it possible to use sticky sessions only for requests to the administration part and use any other form of load balancing(token ring) for the REST API endpoints ?

Can setting web-app to "distributable" in web-xml :

```
<web-app>
    <distributable/>
</web-app>
```

and adding this to jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
  <replication-config>
     <cache-name>web.dist</cache-name>
  </replication-config>
</jboss-web>
```

do the trick ?

Comment: I don't follow: in case you lose a node in your cluster, your load balancer will simply forward an incoming request to another available node. If the request is coming in with a session token, the user continues to use your application without a problem; similarly, a REST request continues to function and isn't affected by session activity because it doesn't carry a session token. Where is the problem? Or rather, what are you trying to achieve by having sticky sessions for one side of the application and session replication for another?

Comment: Also consider that configuring sticky sessions and session replication occurs in different places: your application will generally have settings for session replication (in addition to app server support settings) and a web server (or a load balancer) takes care of sticky sessions.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. Web applications use session failover. In case of session replication, no sticky session is needed, right ?
2. I want to achieve a situation where requests without session token are not redirected to one node only (sticky session). Is this normal behavior of load balancers ?

Comment: 1) Correct 2) It's possible, but how it's done will depend on your specific load balancer. [Here's an example for F5](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/need-an-irule-to-enable-sticky-sessions-for-certain-url)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, not it is clear to me.